# Counting number of records with matching values in separate fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count

database/SQL novice here.
I have a table in DB MS SQL Server 2008 that looks like this:

```
number of request,      employee,   parameter1, parameter2, parameter3
ID1139151   employee1   1   1   0
ID1139152   employee1   0   0   1
ID1139153   employee1   0   1   0
ID1139154   employee2   0   0   1
ID1139155   employee2   0   1   1
ID1139156   employee2   1   1   0
ID1139157   employee3   0   1   0
ID1139158   employee3   0   1   0
```

I want to find number of rows by values parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, number of request

Result should be like this:

```
SUMM number of request,     employee,   SUMM parameter1,    SUMM parameter2,    SUMM parameter3
3   employee1   1   2   1
3   employee2   1   2   2
2   employee3   0   2   0
```

How can I do it? Please help me.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `SUM`, `COUNT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count([number of request]),
       employee,
       sum(parameter1) as sum_p1,
       sum(parameter2) as sum_p2,
       sum(parameter3) as sum_p3
from your_table
group by employee
```

Comment: You've not even explained what you are doing or why this works.  Put at least some effort in?

Answer (score 3):

When you start to use SQL you will realise that - certainly for the simpler queries - you are basically writing really simple sentences in English, with a few words missing.

If you consider the english statement:

```
I want to select this column and that column from this table where that column's value is 1
```

you can format it thus:

```
I want to:
select this column
       and that column
from this table
where that column's value = 1
```

and you will probably see where this is going into pure SQL:

```
select ThisColumn
      ,ThatColumn
from ThisTable
where ThatColumn = 1
```

---

You can then make this a little more complicated by adding aggregation, grouped across certain columns:

```
I want to:
select this column
       and count all the rows that are returned
       and add up all the values in that column
from this table
grouped by the different values in this column
```

which in SQL looks like:

```
select ThisColumn
      ,count(ThatColumn) as ThatColumnCount
      ,sum(ThatColumn) as ThatColumnTotal
from ThisTable
group by ThisColumn
```

---

If you can understand the above, you should be able to write your own scripts without too many issues.  Certainly none that can't be solved without Google until you get into the more complex stuff.